# Добавление нового поля в связанную таблицу mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Скажем, для примера у меня есть две таблицы:

```
table1
------
id
name
```

и

```
table2
------
id
secondName
```

Таблицы связаны по **id**

Я делаю запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM  `table1` LEFT JOIN  `table2` USING (id)
```

И в итоге получаю след. поля:

```
id
name
secondName
```

с которыми дальше работаю в php и обрабатывю как массив через mysql_fetch_row

Но вот в чем вопрос. Скажем, я забыл одно из полей, и добавляю в первую таблицу новое поле, теперь таблица такая:

```
table1
-----
id
name
bd
```

Делаю такой же запрос, как выше и получаю:

```
id
name
bd
secondName
```

Но проблема в том, что уже в коде индексы в массиве были другие и теперь все сдивнулось. Как с этим можно бороться? Понимаю, что можно делать выборку только нужных столбцов или еще как-то. Но вот например можно как-то этот новый столбец добавлять в конец, чтобы было так:

```
id
name
secondName
bd
```

Спасибо

Comment: используйте в место `mysql_fetch_row` --> `mysql_fetch_assoc` теперь нужно будет обращаться не через индекс, а через название столбца. было `$result[0]` станет `$result['id']`. и добавляйте сколько влезет своих столбцов)

Comment: А еще неплохо бы уточнить что расширением `mysql_` пользовались до 2000 года и те кто пользуется им сейчас - обречены на провал и вечное программирование на php5.3. Пожалуйста, используйте `mysqli` или `PDO`.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев большое спасибо, это же было так просто, но я не знал и не мог найти

Answer (score -1):

Как подсказали в комментариях, то можно использовать `mysql_fetch_assoc` и обращаться не через индекс, а по имени столбца.